# fail to bundle install puma 4.3.5 or gem puma with ruby-2.6.6 on macos-10.15.6

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, bundler

fail to bundle install puma 4.3.5 or gem puma with ruby-2.6.6 on macos-10.15.6
try to bundle dependencies for my project, but puma 4.3.5 occured an error.
someone know about this?

xxxxxxxxxxxx

**here is the error content:**

```
fetching puma 4.3.5
Installing puma 4.3.5 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/lxj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
/Users/lxj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/lxj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200731-28585-1eobsvu.rb extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version in openssl/ssl.h... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /Users/lxj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/lxj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/puma-4.3.5/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:44:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
1 warning generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:145:7: warning: unused variable 'min' [-Wunused-variable]
  int min, ssl_options;
      ^
mini_ssl.c:299:40: warning: function 'raise_error' could be declared with attribute 'noreturn' [-Wmissing-noreturn]
void raise_error(SSL* ssl, int result) {
                                       ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling puma_http11.c
puma_http11.c:203:22: error: implicitly declaring library function 'isspace' with type 'int (int)' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  while (vlen > 0 && isspace(value[vlen - 1])) vlen--;
                     ^
puma_http11.c:203:22: note: include the header <ctype.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'isspace'
1 error generated.
make: *** [puma_http11.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/lxj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/gems/puma-4.3.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/lxj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.6.0/puma-4.3.5/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  puma
```

Comment: but it's ok to install puma 4.0.1

Comment: did you make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.5'` succeeds?

Comment: I think the question was incorrectly closed: the linked answer solves an `openssl` related issue, but as you can see, the posted error has nothing to do with openssl. I can confirm that the error posted by @RickLuo is solved by my proposed answer.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

It seems that the latest version of XCode tools (12 Beta 3) installs a version of Clang (the C compiler used by default on MacOS) that throws an error on implicit functions used on the native extension code of Puma.

The workaround as pointed out [here](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/2304#issuecomment-664448309) is to tell Clang not to treat this behavior as an error.

Try running:

```sh
bundle config build.puma --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
bundle install
```

and it should work.

Comment: upgrade puma to 4.3.6 fixed this issue