# bundle install fails after installing puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, puma

I'm running `bundle install` and it failed in the middle with the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/Mahmoud/dev-reps/non-docker/normal/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/puma-4.3.1/ext/puma_http11
/Users/Mahmoud/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20220308-96584-8zjcoy.rb extconf.rb --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes

...
...
An error occurred while installing puma (4.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install puma -v '4.3.1' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

After some failures to install puma, and after much searching and many trials, I was able to install it through:

```
gem install puma:4.3.1 -- --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

and the gem installed successfully, giving:

```
Building native extensions with: '--with-cflags=-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed puma-4.3.1
Parsing documentation for puma-4.3.1
Done installing documentation for puma after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

My problem currently is that trying `bundle install` again still fails with the same error. Tried restarting terminal, but still same. It's as if puma has not been installed at all. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got bundle to work using:

```
bundle config build.puma --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63201544/3540782)